# ¿Como añadir barras de desplazamiento a un JTextArea y JEditorPane?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando añadir barras de desplazamiento a un `JTextArea` y a un `JEditorPane` usando `JScrollPane`, tanto mi `JTextArea` como mi `JEditorPane` se encuentran dentro de un `JPanel`, este es mi código:

```
public class Compilador extends JFrame {

private JPanel panel;
private JEditorPane editor;
protected static JTextArea salida;
private JScrollPane barraEditor, barraSalida;
private String palabras;
protected static String resultados;
private int nlineas;



public Compilador(){
    setSize(900,600);
    setTitle("Mi mini compilador");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(Compilador.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    resultados="";
    nlineas=0;
    Panel();

}

private void Panel(){
    panel=new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    AreasTexto_Etiquetas();
        
}


private void AreasTexto_Etiquetas(){
    
    editor=new JEditorPane();
    editor.setBounds(120,40,700,320);
    editor.setFont(new Font("Arial Black",Font.PLAIN,14));

    barraEditor=new JScrollPane(editor);
    barraEditor.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    barraEditor.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    panel.add(barraEditor);
    panel.add(editor);
   
   
   
    salida=new JTextArea();
    salida.setBounds(100,420,700,105);
    salida.setFont(new Font("Arial Black",Font.BOLD,16));
    salida.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    
    barraSalida=new JScrollPane(salida);
    barraSalida.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    barraSalida.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    panel.add(barraSalida);
    panel.add(salida);
    eventos();
}
```

Por lo que he indagado por internet, esta parte de código:

```
barraEditor=new JScrollPane(editor);
barraEditor.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
barraEditor.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Es la que se encarga de añadir la barra de desplazamiento a algún objeto determinado pero no esta funcionando, no sé si estoy haciendo algo mal o me falta más código esta es la primera vez que intento añadir una barra de desplazamiento a algún objeto en Java, alguna idea, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `setBounds` debes aplicarlo a los `JScrollPane`, después de eso tanto el `JEditorPane editor` como el `JTextArea` `salida` se van a ajustar automáticamente a las dimensiones del contenedor de *scrolling*, así:

```
barraEditor=new JScrollPane(editor);
barraEditor.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
barraEditor.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
barraEditor.setBounds(120,40,700,320); 

//...
barraSalida.setBounds(100,420,700,105);
```

Otra corrección puntual es eliminar las lineas `panel.add(editor);` y `panel.add(salida);` puesto que ya se están agregando esos dos componentes via constructor de `JScrollPane`.

**Edito:** Código ampliado.

```
private void AreasTexto_Etiquetas() {
  editor=new JEditorPane();
  //editor.setBounds(120,40,700,320);
  editor.setFont(new Font("Arial Black",Font.PLAIN,14));

  barraEditor=new JScrollPane(editor);
  barraEditor.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
  barraEditor.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
  barraEditor.setBounds(120,40,700,320);

  panel.add(barraEditor);
  //panel.add(editor);

  salida=new JTextArea();
  //salida.setBounds(100,420,700,105);
  salida.setFont(new Font("Arial Black",Font.BOLD,16));
  salida.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

  barraSalida=new JScrollPane(salida);
  barraSalida.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
  barraSalida.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
  barraSalida.setBounds(100,420,700,105);

  panel.add(barraSalida);
  //panel.add(salida);
  eventos();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No funciona jeje, de hecho desaperece el JTextArea y el JEditorPane, solo queda el panel o como debe ser el orden del código, estoy tratando de averiguarlo

Comment: Gracias ya vi lo que me faltaba