# No se muestra el JScrollPane en mi objeto JList

Tags: java

Estoy creando un programa, y creé un objeto `JList`, y lo llené de los nombres de los archivos de una carpeta, y la lista se llena correctamente y todo, pero como son demasiados archivos, quiero agregarle a la lista un `JScrollPane` para poder leer todos, pero el problema es que no se muestra el `JScrollPane`, todo lo demás se ve correctamente.

```
package gb.ventanas;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Ventana extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 210617741514855925L;
    
    JList<String> ListaArchivos;
    JScrollPane ScrollLista;
    JPanel VentanaPrincipal;
    
    Ventana(){
        
        Dimension DimMax = new Dimension((int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth(), (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight() - 50);
        
        File carpeta = new File("");//no muestro el cómo saco la carpeta porque la tomo de otro lado
        File[] archivos = carpeta.listFiles();
        String[] nombreArchivos = new String[archivos.length];
        int i = 0;
        
        for(File n : archivos) {
            nombreArchivos[i] = n.getName();
            i++;
        }
        
        VentanaPrincipal = new JPanel();
        VentanaPrincipal.setLayout(null);
        
        ListaArchivos = new JList<String>(nombreArchivos);
        ListaArchivos.setLocation((int) (DimMax.getWidth() - 296), 10);
        ListaArchivos.setSize(256, (int) (DimMax.getHeight() - 20));
        ScrollLista = new JScrollPane();
        ScrollLista.setViewportView(ListaArchivos);
        ListaArchivos.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        
        VentanaPrincipal.add(ScrollLista);
        VentanaPrincipal.add(ListaArchivos);
        
        add(VentanaPrincipal);
        setSize(DimMax);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Ventana m = new Ventana();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```

Todo el resto del código funciona correctamente, solo no muestra el `JScrollPane`. Gracias por su atención.

Comment: Tu programa está experimentando el mismo bug que fué corregido con ésta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/390381/como-añadir-barras-de-desplazamiento-a-un-jtextarea-y-jeditorpane/390404#390404

Answer (score 0):

En un comentario te plantean dónde está el problema. Yo no tengo mucho conocimiento, pero como solución al problema que tienes he cambiado el layout (que usas null en la ventana principal). A parte, si te fijas añades la lista tanto al JPanel principal como al JScrollPanel (supongo que esto lo haces porque no conseguias añadir la lista al JScroll).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Ventana extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 210617741514855925L;

    JList<String> ListaArchivos;
    JScrollPane ScrollLista;
    JPanel VentanaPrincipal;

    Ventana(){

        Dimension DimMax = new Dimension((int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth(), (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight() - 50);

        File carpeta = new File("./");//no muestro el cómo saco la carpeta porque la tomo de otro lado
        File[] archivos = carpeta.listFiles();
        String[] nombreArchivos = new String[archivos.length];
        int i = 0;

        for(File n : archivos) {
            nombreArchivos[i] = n.getName();
            i++;
        }

        VentanaPrincipal = new JPanel();
        VentanaPrincipal.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        ListaArchivos = new JList<String>(nombreArchivos);
        ListaArchivos.setLocation((int) (DimMax.getWidth() - 296), 10);
        ListaArchivos.setSize(256, (int) (DimMax.getHeight() - 20));
        ScrollLista = new JScrollPane(
                ListaArchivos
        );
        ListaArchivos.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        VentanaPrincipal.add(ScrollLista,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(VentanaPrincipal);
        setSize(DimMax);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Ventana m = new Ventana();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]